# How to convert simple array to an array of consecutive pairs of its elements using LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

What is the easiest way to convert **[a, b, c, d]**  to an array of consecutive pairs of its elements using `LINQ` **[[a, b], [c, d]]** ? Is it possible at all?

> x = [a, b, c, d] → y = [[a, b], [c, d]]

P.S. If not LINQ then how it can be done in a simplest and efficient way?

Comment: So you want to pair even and odd elements from the original array?

Comment: what should happen if the number of elements is odd?

Comment: [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) features a `Batch` method that can do this.

Comment: @wbennett I need to pair elements only.

Comment: @Dennis_E It is not important.  a,b,c,d  can be any integer number.

Comment: Order doesn't matter? And yes, as @Dennis_E stated, to have everything paired you would need an even quantity.

Comment: @ClarkKent What I meant was: what should happen if you have for example [a,b,c,d,e] What should happen with e? But now I guess the array will always contain an even number of items.

Comment: var pairs = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length / 2).Select(index => Tuple.Create(array[index * 2], array[index * 2 + 1]).ToArray();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, :

```
var result = yourCollection
             .Select((x,idx) => new { x, idx })
             .GroupBy(g => g.idx / 2)
             .Select(g => g.Select(p => p.x).ToArray())
             .ToArray();
```

Since there is no built-in method to do this directly, the code looks like messy.It would be better if you can use `Batch` method from [`MoreLINQ`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library.Then you can just use:

```
var result = yourCollection.Batch(2).Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's awesome and working solution! I appreciate time you spent and your knowledge, man! Thank you very much!